# saltstack 'Pillar failed to render with the following messages'

Tags: salt-stack

I'm getting the following error message when I do a `state.apply`:

```
[ERROR   ] Data passed to highstate outputter is not a
valid highstate return: {'sonia9': ['Pillar failed to
render with the following messages:', "Rendering SLS 'users'
failed. Please see master log for details."]}
```

Is it possible to see the actually rendering and where it failed?

I've already tried:

- `log_level: garbage` in `/etc/salt/master`, restarted daemon
- `salt-call -l debug state.apply` on the minion

I get the same *unhelpful* error message, and no more detail about the actual rendering.

Comment: and there is nothing useful in `/var/log/salt/master`?

Comment: could you post the content of that sls ? or the pillar that being used in that sls ?

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes it can happen that minion has stale cache. I have experience with the frustration when salt is reporting that something failed to render but that "something" is no longer listed in the top.sls files and saltmaster log doesn't say anything at all.

What can help in this case is to [refresh grains](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.saltutil.html#salt.modules.saltutil.refresh_grains) on the affected minion (also refreshes pillars by default):

```
salt <target_host_pattern> saltutil.refresh_grains
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found that if your pillar has duplicates  In my case the same package was listed in the yaml twice. (long List)  it would fail to complile but give no reason..   so to shorten the answer you may have to just clean your pillar and  1980's debug the file

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `users.sls` under your pillar location (mostly `/srv/pillar`) is not correctly formed.
Run > `salt sonia9 pillar.items` OR `salt minion state.sls filename`to check it